# Taking sum of std::vector is using references instead of values?

Tags: c++

I have a vector containing integer values, which I wish to sum. However, it's summing the total wrong - if the vector holds 10 ints between -10 and 10, my total should not be `18446744073709551602`.

I declare the vector, and populate it with values:

```
std::vector<int> X;
for ( int i = 0; i < readings.size() ; ++i ) { 
    X.push_back(readings[i].x);
```

I then sum and display:

```
unsigned long temptotal = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < readings.size() ; ++i ) {
    std::cout << "Value in X: " << X[i] << std::endl;
    temptotal += X[i];
}
std::cout << "Temp total: " << temptotal << std::endl;
```

which produces the following output: `Temp total: 18446744073709551603`.

When I step through the summation loop in GDB, (at `temptotal += X[i];`), I can `print X[i]`:

```
(gdb) p X[i]
$1 = (reference) @0x100100c80: -1
```

Printing `temptotal` before and after the addition is performed:

```
(gdb) p temptotal
$2 = 0
(gdb) p temptotal
$3 = 18446744073709551615
```

I'm fairly sure that I'm adding the memory locations rather than the values in the memory locations - I could be wrong on that - but I'm not sure why I'm not adding the values at `X[i]`. When I populate `X` with the values from `readings[i].x`, they're `double`s, which I then type-cast to `int`s. Is this where my error is? Checking in GDB, my type-cast of the `readings[i].x` value should be an int, or, at least, a number of some kind:

```
(gdb) p (int)readings[i].x
$1 = -1
```

I'm stumped; if somebody could shed some light on why I'm not adding what I think I'm adding, I'd be grateful.

EDIT
It's the casting from `int` to `unsigned long`. I went over it and over it, pressed "submit question" and spotted my error. Although, I still don't understand **why** it's doing what it's doing - any light shed on that would be wonderful - why, if I'm adding an `int` to an `unsigned long`, does it not take the value from the `int`?

Comment: It does. But negative `int` turns into very large `unsigned long` and then is added to your `temptotal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `temptotal` is unsigned. All numbers added to it are *interpreted* as unsigned, hence small negative numbers become large positive numbers in [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 2):

No, you are taking 1 away from your `unsigned long` and it's wrapping round.

Also, use `std::accumulate`:

```
result = std::accumulate(readings.begin(), readings.end(), 0);
```

Comment: A minor gotcha with `accumulate`: if you're adding doubles make sure the last argument is `0.0` otherwise the template magic will assume you're summing `int`s and you will get strange results.

Comment: Similarly, when adding unsigned values, the last argument should be `0U` since you want the result to be unsigned as well. In general, `T std::accumulate(Iter, Iter, T initialValue)` will not try to deduce `T` from `Iter` but just use `T initialValue`.

Answer (score 2):

You asked in your edit as to why this is happening. This is due to the binary representation of integral types in memory.

In the simple case of `unsigned int` you can think of any *positive* number as the direct representation of it in binary, that is

```
1 == 0b1
2 == 0b10
...
42 == 0b101010
```

Each number is stored in some limited amount of memory, and for `int` that is usually 32bits (or 4 bytes). This means that all the bits to the left of the representations above are zeros.

An int however, is signed, so that information has to be stored somewhere. It just so happens to be [Twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is a convenient binary representation for signed integers in binary (read up on it). What it means is that for `int`s

```
0 = 0b0
-1 = 0b11111111111111111111111111111111 (32 bits of all ones)
```

As you might be realizing now, when you convert an `int` to an `unsigned int` instead of a negative number you get a very large positive number, due to the binary representations of these numbers. In general you don't want to mix unsigned and signed integers in your calculations unless you know precisely what you're doing.